# I would like to add a click eventlistener on each row elements of the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, event-listener

I created a 3x3 table for my tic-tac-toe game using the table tag and i added a click event listener to the each of the row using forEach loop but unfortunately nothing is showing in my console

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const strategy = document.querySelector('#strategy');
const restartBtn = document.querySelector('#restart');
const arry = [];
const tick_x = 'X';
const tick_o = 'O';
const userAction = () => {
  boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener('click', function clk() {
      console.log("clicked")
    })
  })
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: teal;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Itim", cursive;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.row1 td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.row2 td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.row3 td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.r11 {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <p class="name">TIC-TAC-TOE</p>
  <h2 id="strategy"></h2>
  <p class="player">Player X'S turn</p>
</div>
<table>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td class="r11">
      <h1 class="box" id="0"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r12">
      <h1 class="box" id="1"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r13">
      <h1 class="box" id="2"> </h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td class="r21">
      <h1 class="box" id="3"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r22">
      <h1 class="box" id="4"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r23">
      <h1 class="box" id="5"> </h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row3">
    <td class="r31">
      <h1 class="box" id="6"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r32">
      <h1 class="box" id="7"> </h1>
    </td>
    <td class="r33">
      <h1 class="box" id="8"> </h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="restart"><h3>Reset</h3></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a single event handler for the whole table rather than creating one for each row. (This used to be known as a "delegated event handler.")

That would look like this:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table')

function onClickCell( event, cellId ) {
    // this is invoked when a cell is clicked
    console.log(`onClickCell`, cellId)
}

// this is the delegated event handler
table.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // figure out which table cell it occurs within
    let td = event.target.closest('.box')
    // if click wasn't inside a cell (e.g. was in gutter), don't fire the cell-click handler
    if(!td) return true
    
    // click WAS inside a cell: fire cell-click handler with some helpful data
    let cellId = td.getAttribute('id')
    return onClickCell(event, cellId)
})
```

Some reasons for using a delegated event handler:

- **Better runtime performance**

  Admittedly, this is less of an issue with modern browsers than it was 10 years ago, and isn't a major problem given that your use-case is so small, but it's still a good practice.
- **One handler is easier to manage than three**

  You will want clicks on the table to do different things depending on the current game phase. During the "gameplay" phase, clicking on a cell should claim the cell for the active player. Before gameplay begins, maybe there is no visible grid of cells, or maybe you have an invented mechanic for choosing which player goes first. After the gameplay phase, you may want clicking on a cell to reveal on which turn that cell was claimed (so players can study the game they just finished). No matter what you've got in mind, having a single root-level click handler for the table will drastically simplify the job of re-wiring how clicks are handled.
- **Survivability**

  If you modify the document, either by overwriting some `innerHTML`, or by using the DOM API to modify nodes, you'll obliterate existing click handlers that are attached to the modified portion of the document. But a delegated handler is, by definition, attached to a distant ancestor of the relevant part of the DOM, meaning it will survive and stay active.
- **Define your own API**

  You have zero control over the arguments that the browser provides to a regular DOM event handler. But a delegated handler can pass *any data you want* to your specialty function, meaning you can define a custom API for the functions it calls. In my example, I make the delegated handler do the work of grabbing the cell's ID, and then it passes that value as an argument to the cell-click handler; that's work the cell-click handler no longer needs to do. The delegated handler could also collect other info about the current game state and provide that to the cell-click handler. A delegated handler can also selectively ignore some some clicks, or call additional functions, or even call the cell-click function multiple times -- essentially letting you invent new kinds of events. A more sophisticated version might even fire literal [CustomEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) that are listened for at the document level.

Answer (score 0):

You never call userAction, so you can either call it or wrap it in a closure and call it (as below)

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const strategy = document.querySelector('#strategy');

const restartBtn = document.querySelector('#restart');

const arry = [];

const tick_x = 'X';

const tick_o = 'O';

(() => {

boxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener('click', function clk () {
        
        console.log("clicked")
    })
})
})()
```

```css
html{

height: 100%;
} body{

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: teal;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: "Itim", cursive;
}

.game{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; } p{ color: white; text-align: center; margin: 40px auto; width: 200px; }

table{

margin-bottom: 50px;
border-radius: 10px;
border-top: 2px solid white;
border-left: 2px solid white;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
border-right: 2px solid white;
}

button{

width: 100px;
} h1{ width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;

}

.row1 td{

width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.row2 td{

width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.row3 td{

width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.r11 {

border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="intro">
        <p class="name">TIC-TAC-TOE</p>
        <h2 id="strategy"></h2>
        <p class="player">Player X'S turn</p>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td class="r11"><h1 class = "box" id ="0"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r12"><h1 class = "box" id ="1"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r13"><h1 class = "box" id ="2"> </h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td class="r21"><h1 class="box" id ="3"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r22"><h1 class="box" id ="4"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r23"><h1 class="box" id ="5"> </h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row3">
            <td class="r31"><h1 class="box" id ="6"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r32"><h1 class="box" id ="7"> </h1></td>
            <td class="r33"><h1 class="box" id ="8"> </h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="restart"><h3>Reset</h3></button>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks I actually forgot to call the function..

Answer (score 0):

You create the `userAction` function, but never call it.
Add at the end:

`userAction()`

Comment: Thanks tom your answer was really helpful 